# Error de Insert en un Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, script, base-de-datos

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy ejecutando un script que hace una exportación de un servidor SQL Server 2012 hacia otro Servidor SQL Server que está atado mediante un Linked Server, el script es el siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO [192.168.10.82].[INTERFAZ_IQWARE].[dbo].[T_FACTURACLI] (IDFactura, FechaDocumento, NombreCliente, NIT, DireccionFacturacion, Folio, Subfolio, Habitacion, Serie, NumeroDoc, IdVendedor, IDClienteIQware, IDClienteSAP, DocType)
SELECT
IDFactura,
FechaDocumento,
NombreCliente,
NIT,
DireccionFacturacion,
Folio,
Subfolio,
Habitacion,
Serie,
NumeroDoc,
IdVendedor,
IDClienteIQware,
IDClienteSAP,
DocType
FROM [T_FACTURACLI]
WHERE (FechaDocumento = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate - 1 FROM prProperty))
```

El problema es que me logueo con el usuario sa y el script funciona correctamente, pero al configurar un Job para que el proceso se haga automáticamente el procedimiento falla, incluso ya coloque al usuario sa como owner del Job y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: y falla con que error?

Answer (score 1):

Indistintamente de cual sea el Owner del Job se va a ejecutar con los permisos de la cuenta que tiene el servicio SQL Server Agent configurada (herramientas administrativas - Servicios)

En este tengo 3 sugerencias a evaluar:

1. Agregar el usuario del servicio a la instancia del linked server y
   darle los permisos correspondientes.
2. Crear un procedimiento almacenado y agregarle la cláusula exec as user = 'sa'
3. Crear un ETL con SSIS

Comment: Agregué la autenticación del usuario NTSERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT a los usuario autenticados en el Linked Server y funcionó

Comment: Excelente @GioGómez por favor procede a marcar la respuesta como la correcta, de ese modo ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar soluciones confiables

Answer (score 0):

Este es el error:

> Message Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. The OLE DB
>   provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "192.168.10.82" reported an
>   error. Authentication failed. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399)  Cannot
>   initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for
>   linked server "192.168.10.82". [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7303)  OLE DB
>   provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "192.168.10.82" returned
>   message "Invalid authorization specification". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error
>   7412).  NOTE: The step was retried the requested number of times (2)
>   without succeeding.  The step failed.

Comment: Leíste mi respuesta? es un tema de persmisos.

Comment: Perdón, no había actualizado, probaré hacer lo que me dices y mantendré esto al tanto